# Where did Menthuthuyoupi's eyes go?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 116 of Hunter X Hunter 2011 we can see Menthuthuyoupi aka Youpi in the begining, but where did all the eyes that where covering him go ? We can still see the gray spot that was supposed to cover one of the eyes but non of the eyes seem to be there. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an Enhancer, Youpi's ability "Metamorphosis" allows him to shape-shift at will<sup>(1)</sup> (such as giving himself wings, as seen earlier in the series). This allows him to hide and reveal those eyes at will.

[image: Youpi's eyes]

<sub>1) [Menthuthuyoupi - Hunter x Hunter Wiki](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Menthuthuyoupi#Nen)</sub>